# SQL query for Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 tables in oracle . users and profile table.
i am running following query to get results

```
SELECT fu.user_name ,papf.SSN  
FROM apps.fnd_user fu, apps.per_all_people_f papf
WHERE fu.employee_id = papf.person_id 
  AND  (TO_CHAR(papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) IS NULL 
   OR  papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE > SYSDATE )
```

Thing is that ,
Profile table has multiple records for SSN.
So this query is returning dupes for SSN.
I just want to get one distinct record for SSN.

for eg result is like

```
ABC 123
ABC 123
```

How do i just display unquie values for SSN
Like

```
ABC 123
```

U tried distinct but did not work
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why wouldn't distinct work.  The only reasons it wouldn't is if you have spaces or non display characters around the user name or ssn...

Comment: I think i am using wrong syntax for distinct. trying like this SELECT fu.user_name ,(select DISTINCT papf.SSN)  
FROM apps.fnd_user fu, apps.per_all_people_f papf
WHERE fu.employee_id = papf.person_id 
  AND  (TO_CHAR(papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) IS NULL 
   OR  papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE > SYSDATE )

Comment: no distinct should go after the select and evaluates all columns (duplicate records are those whose have all columns match, thus the duplicate is removed via distinct) so `select distinct col1, col2... ` distinct can be used when evaluting counts too as in `Select count(Distinct ssn) from table` which will only count unique ssns.

Answer (score 0):

Proper use of Distinct for your case...

```
SELECT Distinct fu.user_name , papf.SSN
FROM apps.fnd_user fu
   , apps.per_all_people_f papf 
WHERE fu.employee_id = papf.person_id 
  AND (TO_CHAR(papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) IS NULL 
       OR papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE > SYSDATE )
```

Comment: ...and if you really wanted to help the OP, you would point out that it makes no sense to call `to_char()` on the effective end date just to check if it's null...

Answer (score 0):

Query using group by can be like below to have a single record:

```
SELECT fu.user_name ,
       papf.SSN      
FROM apps.fnd_user fu, 
     apps.per_all_people_f papf
WHERE fu.employee_id = papf.person_id 
  AND  ( papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE IS NULL 
   OR  papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE > trunc(SYSDATE) --assuming effective_end_date doesnot have timestamp with it.
   )
group by  fu.user_name,
          papf.SSN  ;
```